# Spring Data Neo4j: How do I pull a list of nodes of which I do not know the type?

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j, graph-databases

I'm using Spring Data Neo4j and I'd like to pull a list of owners. An owner can be a `:Person` (human) or an `:Entity` (company). I'm not sure what `Type<T>` should be. I could use in the `GraphRepository<Type>` interface.

My Query is:

```
MATCH ()-[r:OWNED_BY]->(o) RETURN
```

And this is the code I tried:

```
public interface Owners extends GraphRepository<Object> {

    @Query("start o=MATCH ()-[r:OWNED_BY]->(o) RETURN o;")
    Iterable<Object> getOwners();

}
```

I had an idea that I could perhaps extend a common base class, such as `PersistentBaseObject` with an id and a name, or an interface like `HasIdAndName`. Not sure how I'd integrate this though,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes,you could extend a common base class, perhaps like this-

```
public class Owner {

    Long id;
   String name;
...
}

public class Person extends Owner {

    private int age;
...
}
public class Entity extends Owner {

    private String location;
...
}
```

And add a matching repository for Owner

```
public interface OwnerRepository extends GraphRepository<Owner> {

}
```

which will allow you to do stuff such as `ownerRepository.findAll()`
But since you're using a @Query, there is no reason you can't put this method on even the PersonRepository (at least in SDN 4. I'm not sure about SDN 3.x)

```
 @Query("start o=MATCH ()-[r:OWNED_BY]->(o) RETURN o;")
 Iterable<Owner> getOwners();
```

Note however, that now your Person and Entity nodes are going to have an extra Owner label.

EDIT:

The additional label can be avoided by changing Owner to an interface.
Then the @Query on a repository returning a collection of Owner should still work.

Comment: thanks for your response. Is there a more elegant solution, perhaps pulling back an iterator of Node and casting them, or using an interface? I really don't like the idea of un-needed labels.

Comment: In SDN 4.0 there's no access to a Node. Edited my answer to use an interface instead and skip the additional label

Comment: Is there a generic node we can extend - I see that I can cast the base node back to the original node which is truly awesome, so if we could do something like "extends Node" then we'd be set!

Comment: Nothing generic in sdn 4 I'm afraid, but perhaps you could create such a generic class in your app